# How to loop though XML type and insert record every iteration in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I want to create a stored procedure which has a `varchar(max)` parameter which serves as a container for the XML string I constructed in my application. I have managed to come up with this xml string which will be passed as a `varchar(max)` parameter to the stored procedure and will be cast to XML:

```
<SurveyQuestion>
    <Name>What is your pets name?</Name>
    <Type>1</Type>
    <IsRequired>True</IsRequired>
    <Answer></Answer>
</SurveyQuestion>
<SurveyQuestion>
    <Name>What is your gender?</Name>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <IsRequired>True</IsRequired>
    <Answer>Male</Answer>
    <Answer>Female</Answer>
    <Answer>Trans</Answer>
</SurveyQuestion>
<SurveyQuestion>
    <Name>Which colors do you like?</Name>
    <Type>4</Type>
    <IsRequired>False</IsRequired>
    <Answer>Yellow</Answer>
    <Answer>Green</Answer>
    <Answer>Red</Answer>
    <Answer>Blue</Answer>
    <Answer>Orange</Answer>
</SurveyQuestion>
<SurveyQuestion>
    <Name>Rate the service that you have receive from 1 to 5. I being the lowest and 5 being the highest</Name>
    <Type>2</Type>
    <IsRequired>True</IsRequired>
    <Answer>1</Answer>
    <Answer>2</Answer>
    <Answer>3</Answer>
    <Answer>4</Answer>
    <Answer>5</Answer>
</SurveyQuestion>
```

I have `Questions` and an `Answers` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Questions]
(
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Question] [varchar](max) NULL, --Name
    [IsRequired] bit NULL,
    [SurveyFieldObjectId] [bigint] NULL --Type
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Answers]
(
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [QuestionId] [bigint] NULL, --Foreign key Questions
    [Options] [varchar](50) NULL, --Answer
    [SurveyFieldObjectId] [bigint] NULL
)
```

And this is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE
    @otherIrrelevantProperty nvarchar(120),
    @varcharXML varchar(max)
AS 
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @questionsXML = CAST(@varcharXML AS XML)

        BEGIN TRANSACTION INSERTSURVEY
           LOOP(@questionsXML.question)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Questions VALUES (..)

            LOOP(@questionsXML.answers)
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO Answers VALUES (..)
            END
        END

        COMMIT TRANSACTION INSERTSURVEY

        SELECT 1
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 
        IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION INSERTSURVEY
        END 

        SELECT -1
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: Loops and cursors -- not even once. [Query that stuff](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type).

Comment: Is `Name` unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Name` is unique in your XML, you can do this using two `INSERT` and temp table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Questions
(
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Question] [varchar](max) NULL --Name
)

CREATE TABLE #Answers
(
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [QuestionId] [bigint] NULL, --Foreign key Questions
    [Options] [varchar](50) NULL --Answer
)

declare @xml xml = '<root>
<SurveyQuestion>
    <Name>What is your pets name?</Name>
    <Type>1</Type>
    <IsRequired>True</IsRequired>
    <Answer></Answer>
</SurveyQuestion>
<SurveyQuestion>
    <Name>What is your gender?</Name>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <IsRequired>True</IsRequired>
    <Answer>Male</Answer>
    <Answer>Female</Answer>
    <Answer>Trans</Answer>
</SurveyQuestion>
<SurveyQuestion>
    <Name>Which colors do you like?</Name>
    <Type>4</Type>
    <IsRequired>False</IsRequired>
    <Answer>Yellow</Answer>
    <Answer>Green</Answer>
    <Answer>Red</Answer>
    <Answer>Blue</Answer>
    <Answer>Orange</Answer>
</SurveyQuestion>
<SurveyQuestion>
    <Name>Rate the service that you have receive from 1 to 5. I being the lowest and 5 being the highest</Name>
    <Type>2</Type>
    <IsRequired>True</IsRequired>
    <Answer>1</Answer>
    <Answer>2</Answer>
    <Answer>3</Answer>
    <Answer>4</Answer>
    <Answer>5</Answer>
</SurveyQuestion>
</root>';

CREATE TABLE #temp 
(
    [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Question] [varchar](8000) NOT NULL, --Name, UNIQUE!!!
    CONSTRAINT UC_Question UNIQUE(Question)
);

insert into #Questions (Question)
    output INSERTED.Id, INSERTED.Question
    into #temp (id, question)
    select n.value('.', 'varchar(max)') Name
        from @xml.nodes('/root/SurveyQuestion/Name') xml(n);

insert into #Answers (QuestionId, Options)
    select t.Id, n.value('.', 'varchar(50)') answer
        from #temp t
        cross apply @xml.nodes('/root/SurveyQuestion[Name = sql:column("t.question")]/Answer') answers(n);

select * from #Questions;
select * from #Answers;

drop table #Questions;
drop table #Answers;
drop table #temp;
```